# Networkx TypeError: Input graph is not a networkx graph type

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to create a directed graph using `from_pandas_edgelist`. I'm getting an error while passing the parameter `create_using=nx.DiGraph()`

1) I tried creating a directed graph object and then tried to create a graph using `from_pandas_edgelist` : but it creates all links as bi-directional

```
G=nx.DiGraph()    G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_SearchRelations,source='ParentCompanyId',target='ChildCompanyId',edge_attr=True)
```

2) I tried creating a graph object and then converting using `to_directed()`, but no luck

```
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_SearchRelations,source='From',target='To',edge_attr=True)
G=G.to_directed()
```

Expected result:
overcome the error of `TypeError: Input graph is not a networkx graph type`

PS: the same code used to work, but is suddenly failing. I am unsure if it is a version compatibility issue or an issue with the dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `create_using` parameter:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_SearchRelations,
                            source='ParentCompanyId',
                            target='ChildCompanyId',
                            edge_attr=True, 
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the Directed graph generator will through an error when every nodes are not connected in a graph. so when we pass the edge_list as pandas dataframe, we should check whether there are any disconnected subgraphs/nodes.